# Python Urllib POST response is not fetching correct values

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

For learning POST parmaeter urllib, I'm trying to grab table values for a particular date in the following code entered in the parameters. However, it doesn't return the values for 12th September but instead response shows the date is 12th October.

Using POSTMAN, the response is returned for the correct date but with Python, I'm unable to obtain values for other than current month. Any explanation to what could be causing this? any help/suggestion is appreciated.

```
import urllib
import urllib2


url = ''

data = urllib.urlencode({'priceDate.month' : '09', 'priceDate.date' : '12','priceDate.year':'2016','submit':'Show Prices'})
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

d = response.read()

print d
```

Comment: Why are you using both urllib and urllib2?

Comment: @ChrisKenyon As per documentation, I need to encode POST parameters (urllib.urlencode) and it's possible with urllib library . urllib2 is to send the POST request. So both libraries are needed.

Comment: Perhaps it's using a zero-based array for the month (i.e. months are '00' thru '11')?  Try submitting '08'.

Comment: @JohnGordon That's a good point , but using POSTMAN , I can retrieve for September with 09. However, I tried with '08' too and its still giving me value for October. :(

Comment: This can't be the actual code you're using, as `headers` is undefined.  Please show us the real, full code.

Comment: Are you sure that September should be `09` instead of just `9`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry about that, I just removed the headers. It's not required. this is the only code.
Yup I did try by 09 and 9. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: `'priceDate.date' : '12'` Shouldn't that be `.day`?

Comment: Yes! That was the issue. I was using date instead of day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `requests` module.

```
import requests as re
url = "https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm"
parms = {'priceDate.month':'09','priceDate.day':'12','priceDate.year':'2016','submit':'CSV+Format'}
resp = re.post(url, parms)
resp.content
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but  I was hoping to retrieve  the  page along with the html tags. Is it possible using the requests module?

Comment: Just changed the submit parameter to Show Prices and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still Curious, why the urllib would not retrieve the same page as requests module?